# Best way to manage and load avro schema files with kafka and schema registry on python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am new with avro and kafka in python. I have used it a lot with Java and Maven.

With Java and Maven you add avro schema files (.avsc) to a specific folder and the configure the specific maven plugin on then pom file. When you build or compile the plugins do it all the work publish the scema to the schema registry and compile all the avro schemas into `SpecificRecord`.

With python it is  a little bit different because there is no compilation from avro schema to a python class.

In order to load the schemas to the schema registry and use specific classes for my avro messages I have done something like the following:

- create a folder where i have put all my avro schemas `avro_events`
- inside the `avro_event` folder I have add another folder colled`python` with a `.py` file for each schema defined in the `avro_event` folder. Each `.py` files load the schema into an `AvroRecord` from `kafkian` lib:

  ```
    from confluent_kafka import avro
    from kafkian.serde.avroserdebase import AvroRecord

    schema_path = "./avro_events/SchemaTest.avsc"

    class SchemaTest(AvroRecord):
       f = open(schema_path, "rb")
       _schema = avro.loads(f.read())
  ```
- when my app starts I register all the schemas in the `avro_events` folder using confluent schema registry api for python:

  ```
      def register_schemas():
        avro_folder = `avro_events`
        file_names = os.listdir(avro_folder)
        for file_name in file_names:
            path = avro_folder + "/" + file_name
            if not os.path.isdir(path):
                f = open(path, "rb")
                schema_def = f.read()
                avro_schema = schema.AvroSchema(json.loads(schema_def))
                subject_name = file_name.replace(".avsc","")
                schema_id = self.__client.register(subject_name, avro_schema)
                self.__logger.info(str.format("Registered {} schema with id {}", subject_name, schema_id))
                f.close()
  ```

I don't like so much my solution, but I can't find any example on how to handle this scenario. There is a better way to register avro schema (from . avsc file) and generate `AvroRecord` to use on event publishing?

Comment: In a previous job, we basically people to use "empty" Maven projects that just compiled and registered schemas. Then built CI/CD pipelines that published Java classes and schemas to Artifactory (and the Registry). Should external clients choose to do so, they downloaded the schemas from either location at application startup, in-memory, not actually stored the files

Comment: My problem is with python not Java. Using maven is very easy!

Comment: Right, but there's no reason you cannot use both if your CI tooling supports both (most do). Regardless, my point is that you can download the a specific schema version from the Registry after it's been registered (and checked for compatibility) rather than storing any schema file in the project